Gerrit send js `fetch` to post a reply to a patch
With a gerrit server at http://<server>/, I want to use javascript to POST a reply to a given patch, and that reply should be from my user account. If I manually send a reply using the gerrit UI and then use the inspector to copy a fetch command, I get something like:
await fetch("http://builder.cubespace.co.za:8080/changes/sofia~2366/revisions/4/review", {
    "credentials": "include",
    "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-gerrit-auth": "abc",
        "Priority": "u=0"
    },
    "body": "{\"drafts\":\"PUBLISH_ALL_REVISIONS\",\"labels\":{\"Code-Review\":0,\"Verified\":0,\"MISRA\":0,\"Style\":0,\"Unit-Tests\":0,\"Doxygen\":0,\"Python\":0,\"Regression-Jig\":0,\"Regression-Jig-CC\":0},\"message\":\"Example reply for testing\",\"reviewers\":[]}",
    "method": "POST",
    "mode": "cors"
});

or as a cURL request (I've replaced cookies/auth with abc, bcd, cde, etc):
curl \
    'http://builder.cubespace.co.za:8080/changes/sofia~2366/revisions/4/review' \
    -X POST \
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0' \
    -H 'Accept: */*' \
    -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' \
    -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    -H 'x-gerrit-auth: abc' \
    -H 'Origin: http://builder.cubespace.co.za:8080' \
    -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
    -H 'Cookie: _ga_RJRD1SNY74=def; _ga=cde; GerritAccount=bcd; XSRF_TOKEN=abc' \
    -H 'Priority: u=0' 
    --data-raw '{"drafts":"PUBLISH_ALL_REVISIONS","labels":{"Code-Review":0,"Verified":0,"MISRA":0,"Style":0,"Unit-Tests":0,"Doxygen":0,"Python":0,"Regression-Jig":0,"Regression-Jig-CC":0},"message":"Example reply for testing","reviewers":[]}'

I want to be able to make a JS fetch request to post custom messages (we have some CI/CD that kicks off based on certain messages being sent, and I want to automate this process a bit more).
I can't figure out how to get the correct value for the auth headers/cookies. This is just a JS snippet for me to run via greasemonkey, so I'm not terribly worried about security just yet.
What I've tried:

I tried looking here, but couldn't see how to convert the Java to JS.

I see here mentions that I might not need the XSRF tokens for automation, but if I omit them I get 403s.

I also see this SO answer says to parse xGerritAuth out of the HTML response, although I'm not sure how I'd do that from JS running in a page that's already been loaded.

The gerrit REST API docs didn't seem to have anything about sending messages.

Asking on stack overflow, although it was said that this was a better place for this sort of question since it seems like the Gerrit API doesn't explicitly have an endpoint for something like this


How do I make a JS fetch request to post authenticated custom messages via the gerrit API?
